# I'm trying to compile C/C++ code in VS Code using mingw installed via visual studio 2019

Tags: c, visual-studio, compiler-errors

i have already installed compiler MINGW for c++/c files.. I've set up the json files like the MS website suggests,
here is my json file

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "gnu11",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x86"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
```

}
and still got the following error :-

```
cd "d:\codes\C-LANGUAGE\" ; if ($?) { gcc q3.c -o q3 } ; if ($?) { .\q3 }
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
```

after installing mingW compiler i get above error

Comment: It looks like you are trying to run stuff but it can't find WinMain.. have you written one? What type of thing are you trying to build?

Comment: PS D:\codes> cd "d:\codes\C-LANGUAGE\" ; if ($?) { gcc q1.c -o q1 } ; if ($?) { .\q1 }
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status   actually I'm a beginner so i don't know about WinMain  but i have already done every step from the youtube

Comment: Have you got a `WinMain` function or a `main` function?

Comment: yes i have used int main in the code

Comment: edit your post and add your code there, cuz it looks like you have no ```main``` function

Comment: You are probably not linking to win32 libs. Try adding `-mwindows` in your tasks.json, under *args*. This uses a few common win32 libs but it also suppresses the console, so you may alternative want to just list your needed libs one after another manually, again under *args*. For example, if your code uses the `InitCommonControlsEx()` func, you should link to *Comctl32.lib* by adding: `-lComctl32` in your build command (meaning, under *args* in your tasks.json file)